# How can I parse JSON from DIO response when response header content-type is 'text/html'?

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit, dio

It seems that DIO parses JSON from response data automatically when the response header's Content-Type is 'application/json'.
But when I received an 'text/html' response, DIO doesn't parse JSON from the response data.
The received data is always JSON object and the API server is providing JSON object data with response header 'text/html' not 'application/json'.

I am using it by adding an `Interceptor` that parses JSON to DIO temporarily.

How can I parse JSON from DIO response Automatically? Is there any dio or retrofit annotation for me??

`createword.dart`

```dart
@RestApi(baseUrl: 'url')
abstract class CreateWord {
  factory CreateWord(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _CreateWord;

  @POST('/saveSet')
  @Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'x-cors-api-key': 'key',
  })
  Future<SaveSet> saveSet(@Body() Map<String, dynamic> params);
}
```

`main.dart`

```dart
Dio dio = Dio()
    ..interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
      onResponse: (res, handler) {
        res.data = jsonDecode(res.data);
        handler.next(res);
      },
    ));
  CreateWord createWord = CreateWord(dio);
```

Comment: Is "fix the bug in the API server" an option?

Comment: The API server is not my own. :'(
I just want to parse the response data automatically from response header Content-Type is text/html.
If my question is confusing, I'm sorry for my English skill

Comment: You don't seem to set any "Accept" headers. Is that something that happens automatically? Maybe if you send the correct request, your will receive a correct reply and don't need your workaround.

Comment: Hmm I tried to set the Accept header to application/json , but the server still responds with text/html.

Comment: You could file a bug with whoever is responsible for it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't..

Comment: This interceptor I'm using automatically parses the data and works well.
However, there is a problem with parsing JSON for all responses. What I want is to parse JSON for a specific request.

Comment: Would you please add an example for the HTML response?

Comment: Oh..! Thank you for helpful solution!
Do you mean that I should add Interceptor which distinguish HTML and JSON?
How can I distinguish HTML and JSON in response?

Comment: Another option is to create a custom transformer by extending the Transformer class and overriding Dio's default transformer. You can achieve this by setting `dio.transformer = CustomTransformer();`.

In case you're wondering, the check that prevents the usage of `jsonDecodeCallback` when the response's `Content-Type` is not one of json's formats can be found in the `sync_transformer.dart` file, specifically at line 120. You can refer to it [here](https://github.com/cfug/dio/blob/1332d3210f83b67deced437aaad9f77abb05201e/dio/lib/src/transformers/sync_transformer.dart#L120)